# Why $\sum_{k=0}^m x^k $ is equal to $\dfrac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Who can help me proving this (but you can no longer use $\sum$ in the proof):

$$\sum_{k=0}^m x^k=\dfrac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: Hint: geometric sum.

Comment: Who not use $\;\sum\;$ in the proof?? To write more and make things more cumbersome? Anyway, the *usual* proof here is by induction. Did you try it?

Comment: There are two main ways to prove this.  The first is to use induction on $m$.  The second is to take the sum, multiply through by $x$ and then you have $\sum=S$ and $x\sum=xS$.  Subtracting the two equations gives $xS-S=x^{m+1}-1$.  Then, solve for the sum $S$.

Comment: @Timbuc Of course you can use $\sum$ to simplify or factorize.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You should make that comment into an answer. In particular the second way is pretty elementary and can be appealing to students who haven't yet studied induction (though also the second way has induction but in a "hidden" way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Develop $(1 - x) \sum_{k= 0 }^m x^k$ : 
$$(1 - x) \sum_{k= 0 }^m x^k  = (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^m) = (1 + x + ...+ x^m ) - (x + x^2 + ... + x^{m+1})$$

There are many identical terms who kill each other, the only remaining are $ 1 - x^{m+1}$. Therefore, $(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^m x^k = 1 - x^{m+1}$, which is what you wanted to prove.